# How can i change the background-image from Typescript in Angular?

Tags: angular, html, typescript

i want to change the background-image from the Typescript file in Agular, i tried but don't work.

I change the style directly in my html file because i don't know how to do in the css.

This is the line in my html file:

```
<div style="background-image: url({{imageName}});"> </div>
```

and this is my Typescript file:

```
export class NAmeComponent implements OnInit {

  imageName: String;

ngOninit(){
this.getImage();
}

getImage(){
 switch (value) {
      case 'a': {
        this.imageName = 'Nebula.jpg';
        break;
      }
     case 'b': {
        this.imageName = 'Eclipse.jpeg';
        break;
      }
    }
}
}
```

How can i fix this? Thank all for the answer!

Comment: try [style.background-image]="'url(' + imageName + ')'"

Comment: you can use something like `<img [src]='yourVariableHere' />`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `[ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + imageName + ')'}"`

Comment: i fight with this problem from 2 days XD